# How can I modify content type of uploaded file in php?

Tags: php, curl, mime-types

I want to use an Image Upload API. It receives Image file via POST and sends me that URI of image which I uploaded. but that API sends me error If Content-Type of image is not a kind of image mime type (such as image/jpeg, image/png, ...)

But when I upload image file via FTP and use CURL as file uploads, It sends me error because Content-Type of that image is always 'application/octet-stream'. I want to modify this mime type. Is there any way to modify this?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$fileUploadPostParams = Array(
    "uploadedfile" => "@/files.jpg"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://uix.kr/widget/parameter.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fileUploadPostParams);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

and here is the result:

```
...
===== file ===== 
Array
(
    [uploadedfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => 2312.jpg
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            ^^^^ I want to change here...
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php5bigGV
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 383441
        )
)
```

sorry for bad english.. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the type in the parameters like this:

```
$fileUploadPostParams = array(
    "uploadedfile" => "@/files.jpg;type=image/jpeg"
);
```

From the [curl's man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html):

> -F accepts parameters like -F "name=contents". If you want the contents to   be read from a file, use <@filename> as contents. When
>   specifying a file,   you can also specify the file content type by
>   appending ';type='

Comment: You can also set a custom file name: `"uploadedfile" => "@/files.jpg;type=image/jpeg;filename=custom_name.jpg"`